# How can I approximate the size of a data structure in scala?

Tags: performance, scala, jvm

I have a query that returns me around 6 million rows, which is too big to process all at once in memory.

Each query is returning a Tuple3[String, Int, java.sql.Timestamp]. I know the string is never more than about 20 characters, UTF8.

How can I work out the max size of one of these tuples, and more generally, how can I approximate the size of a scala data-structure like this?

I've got 6Gb on the machine I'm using. However, the data is being read from the database using scala-query into scala's Lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala objects follow approximately the same rules as Java objects, so any information on those is accurate.  [Here is one source](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml), which seems at least mostly right for 32 bit JVMs.  (64 bit JVMs use 8 bytes per pointer, which generally works out to 4 bytes extra overhead plus 4 bytes per pointer--but there may be less if the JVM is using compressed pointers, which it does by default now, I think.)

I'll assume a 64 bit machine without compressed pointers (worst case); then a `Tuple3` has two pointers (16 bytes) plus an `Int` (4 bytes) plus object overhead (~12 bytes) rounded to the nearest 8, or 32 bytes, plus an extra object (8 bytes) as a stub for the non-specialized version of `Int`.  (Sadly, if you use primitives in tuples they take even *more* space than when you use wrapped versions.).  `String` is 32 bytes, IIRC, plus the array for the data which is 16 plus 2 per character.  `java.sql.Timestamp` needs to store a couple of `Long`s (I think it is), so that's 32 bytes.  All told, it's on the order of 120 bytes plus two per character, which at ~20 characters is ~160 bytes.

Alternatively, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353) for a way to measure the size of your objects directly.  When I measure it this way, I get 160 bytes (and my estimate above has been corrected using this data so it matches; I had several small errors before).

Comment: Good point, I forgot about the extra overhead in the String plus object overhead. Still, it's not very much data.

Comment: Why 24 plus 2 per character on the String array? IIRC, an Array is 8 bytes vs 4 bytes for a non-array, plus the elements.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - There's object overhead plus length, which is 16 bytes on a 64 bit machine, so I was off by a bit.

Answer (score 2):

How much memory have you got at your disposal? 6 million instances of a triple is really not very much!

Each reference has an overhead which is either 4 or 8 bytes, dependent on whether you are running 32- or 64-bit (without compressed "oops", although this is the default in JDK7 for heaps under 32Gb).

So your triple has 3 references (there may be extra ones due to specialisation - so you might get 4 refs), your `Timestamp` is a wrapper (reference) around a `long` (8 bytes). Your `Int` will be specialized (i.e. an underlying `int`), so this makes another 4 bytes. The String is 20 x 2 bytes. So you basically have a worst case of *well under* 100 bytes per row; so 10 rows per kb, 10,000 rows per Mb. So you can comfortably process your 6 million rows in under 1 Gb of heap.

Frankly, I think I've made a mistake here because we process daily several million rows of about twenty fields (including decimals, Strings etc) comfortably in this space.

Comment: Any hindsight about it?